# Разбить файл на части определенного размера(без обрезания строк)

Tags: linux, bash

У меня имеется большой файл csv (около 500 Мб).Мне нужно разделить  файл на несколько файлов размером не более 200 МБ каждый. Я нашел много похожих постов, но ни один из них не отвечает на мой вопрос, потому что во всех постах linux функия split делит исходный файл ровно на 200 МБ и (очевидно) усеченные записи. Вместо этого мне нужно, чтобы каждая запись была полной, неповрежденной.

```
split -a 3 -b 200M --numeric-suffixes=1 --additional-suffix=".csv"
```

Comment: там есть параметр `-l`, который позволяет разбивать на файлы по кол-ву строк. с помощью `wc -l` смотрите, сколько там и на глаз делите

Comment: Нужно писать скрипт на BASH, ибо одной командой сделать это видимо не получится.

Comment: а Вам нужно много раз это делать? или однократно

Comment: попробуйте вот так `split -n l/3 --numeric-suffixes=1 --additional-suffix=".csv" имяфайла` (это поделить на 3 куска, так как 500 / 300 чуть меньше 3

Answer (score 1):

-C, --line-bytes – разбить файл на части не более указанного размера, не разделяя строки/записи внутри него.